# How to plot data from QTableWidget into QChart

Tags: python, qtablewidget, pyside2, qtcharts

I'm working on data analysis software, which takes data from remote database and puts it into *QTableWidget*. How could I effectively get these data from table and put them into *QChart*?

I've seen that if I had been using *QTableView*, it could have been done with models, but as I understand it, using *QTableView* would be far more complicated for my scenario.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtCharts import *
import sys
import random


class DateTimeDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(DateTimeDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        value = index.data()
        option.text = 
QDateTime.fromMSecsSinceEpoch(value).toString("dd.MM.yyyy")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1280, 400)
        self.chart_table()

        self.populate()
    def chart_table(self):
        self.table = QTableWidget(0, 2)
        delegate = DateTimeDelegate(self.table)
        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)
        chart = QtCharts.QChart()
        self.chartView = QtCharts.QChartView(chart)
        self.chartView.setFixedSize(600, 430)

        splitter = QSplitter(self)
        splitter.addWidget(self.table)
        splitter.addWidget(self.chartView)

        self.setCentralWidget(splitter)

        series = QtCharts.QLineSeries(name='Odoslané')
        mapper = QtCharts.QVXYModelMapper(xColumn=0, yColumn=2)
        mapper.setModel(self.table.model())
        mapper.setSeries(series)
        chart.addSeries(mapper.series())

        self.axis_X = QtCharts.QDateTimeAxis()
        self.axis_X.setFormat("MMM yyyy")
        self.axis_Y = QtCharts.QValueAxis()

        chart.setAxisX(self.axis_X, series)
        chart.setAxisY(self.axis_Y, series)
        self.axis_Y.setRange(0, 0)
        self.axis_Y.setLabelFormat('%.0f')
        self.axis_X.setRange(QDate(2017, 10, 1), QDate.currentDate())

        chart.setTitle('Chart')

    def addRow(self, dt, value):
        self.table.insertRow(0)

        for col, v in enumerate((dt.toMSecsSinceEpoch(), value)):
            it = QTableWidgetItem()
            it.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, dt.toMSecsSinceEpoch())
            self.table.setItem(0, 0, it)
        t_m, t_M = self.axis_X.min(), self.axis_X.max()
        t_m = min(t_m, dt)
        t_M = max(t_M, dt)

        m, M = self.axis_Y.min(), self.axis_Y.max()
        m = min(m, value)
        M = max(M, value)
```

In this method I simulate filling table with data as I get them from database.

```
def populate(self):
    for i in range(4):
        count=random.randint(1,40)
        value_str = QDate.currentDate().addDays(count).toString('dd.MM.yyyy')

        dt = QDateTime.fromString(value_str, "dd.MM.yyyy")

        sent = QTableWidgetItem(str(count))
        value = int(sent.text())

        self.addRow(dt, value)
        self.table.setItem(0, 1, sent)
```

And App running function -

```
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = MainWindow()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

Comment: PySide or PySide2? PyQt4 or PyQt5? You could explain what kind of plot you want besides showing the entry. It would also be great if you link the solution with QTableView.

Comment: For the record, I'm using PySide2 (but for the sake of getting answer of the principle, I generalized). I want to use simple _QLineSeries_ chart of x-axis containing _DateTime_ and y-axis real numbers. As for actual solution, there isn't any - that's why I am asking this question.

Comment: Always use the correct tag since each library has its limitations, for example in PySide and PyQt4 there is no QLineSeries. You could place a sample of the QTableWidget: For example what is the format of the datetime?, so I could help you easily

Comment: No, I'm not agree. The main tag is the one that will serve to attract attention (in your case python), and the others indicate the limitations of the answers (as I pointed out in my previous comment certain libraries have/or do not have certain features)

Comment: I'm currently using QDate object formatted to string and then is added to table. If I recall correctly, there's an option to convert it back to QDate

Comment: Okay, I will create my data but it would be annoying if it does not work because you have another format (it has already happened in other answers), so I always ask the OP to show the entry, in your case the QTableWidget

Comment: Sure, right now, I get date from _QDateEdit_ and I format it like this `date().toString('dd.MM.yyyy')`

Comment: Hey, @eyllanesc, could You please comment Your solution for my second question (about another series) here, I can't find it anymore?

Comment: You have to create other QLineSeries, QValueAxis and QVXYModelMapper with yColumn equal to the new column, the other parameters are similar

Comment: @eyllanesc, and if I were to exclude some rows from chart? Let's say I've got column with names of cities and I would like mapper to get data only from the ones with "Washington"?

Comment: Then you have to use a proxy, for example in your case you could use [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html). This question has already spread too much, if you have other questions then you should create another question. goodbye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to show the data of a QTableWidget in a QChartView is to use a QVXYModelMapper that relates the model of the QTableWidget with a QLineSerie. But for this the data stored in the QTableWidget should not be a string but an integer so you should not convert the QDateTime to string using toString(), but to an integer using toMSecsSinceEpoch(), and to show it as datetime in the QTableWidget a delegate should be used.

In the following example the addRow method allows to add a (QDateTime, value) to a row, this recalculates the ranges of each axis.

```py
import random
from functools import partial
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCharts import QtCharts


class DateTimeDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(DateTimeDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        value = index.data()
        option.text = QtCore.QDateTime.fromMSecsSinceEpoch(value).toString("dd.MM.yyyy")


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.m_tablewidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 2)
        delegate = DateTimeDelegate(self.m_tablewidget)
        self.m_tablewidget.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)
        self.m_chartview = QtCharts.QChartView()
        self.m_chartview.chart().setTheme(QtCharts.QChart.ChartThemeQt)
        self.m_chartview.setMinimumWidth(400)

        self.m_series = QtCharts.QLineSeries(name="Time-Value")
        self.m_mapper = QtCharts.QVXYModelMapper(self, xColumn=0, yColumn=1)
        self.m_mapper.setModel(self.m_tablewidget.model())
        self.m_mapper.setSeries(self.m_series)

        self.m_chartview.chart().addSeries(self.m_mapper.series())

        splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self)
        splitter.addWidget(self.m_tablewidget)
        splitter.addWidget(self.m_chartview)
        self.setCentralWidget(splitter)

        self.m_time_axis = QtCharts.QDateTimeAxis()
        self.m_time_axis.setFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")
        self.m_value_axis = QtCharts.QValueAxis()

        self.m_chartview.chart().setAxisX(self.m_time_axis, self.m_series)
        self.m_chartview.chart().setAxisY(self.m_value_axis, self.m_series)

        self.m_value_axis.setRange(0, 0)
        self.m_time_axis.setRange(
            QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime(),
            QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addDays(1),
        )

    def addRow(self, dt, value):
        row = self.m_tablewidget.rowCount()
        self.m_tablewidget.insertRow(row)
        for col, v in enumerate((dt.toMSecsSinceEpoch(), value)):
            it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            it.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, v)
            self.m_tablewidget.setItem(row, col, it)
        t_m, t_M = self.m_time_axis.min(), self.m_time_axis.max()
        t_m = min(t_m, dt)
        t_M = max(t_M, dt)

        m, M = self.m_value_axis.min(), self.m_value_axis.max()
        m = min(m, value)
        M = max(M, value)

        self.m_time_axis.setRange(t_m, t_M)
        self.m_value_axis.setRange(m, M)


counter = 0


def onTimeout(w):
    # Emulate the data
    global counter
    dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addDays(counter)
    value = random.uniform(-100, 100)
    w.addRow(dt, value)

    counter += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    wrapper = partial(onTimeout, w)
    timer = QtCore.QTimer(timeout=wrapper, interval=1000)
    timer.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

---

**Update:**

You do not have to create any QTableWidget in the populate method. I have corrected your logic so that it is added to the top of the QTableWidget, also I have corrected the calculation of the range.

```py
import sys
import random
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCharts import QtCharts


class DateTimeDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(DateTimeDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        value = index.data()
        option.text = QDateTime.fromMSecsSinceEpoch(value).toString("dd.MM.yyyy")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1280, 400)
        self.chart_table()

        self.populate()

    def chart_table(self):
        self.table = QTableWidget(0, 2)
        delegate = DateTimeDelegate(self.table)
        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)
        chart = QtCharts.QChart()
        self.chartView = QtCharts.QChartView(chart)
        self.chartView.setFixedSize(600, 430)

        splitter = QSplitter(self)
        splitter.addWidget(self.table)
        splitter.addWidget(self.chartView)
        self.setCentralWidget(splitter)

        series = QtCharts.QLineSeries(name="Odoslané")
        mapper = QtCharts.QVXYModelMapper(self, xColumn=0, yColumn=1)
        mapper.setModel(self.table.model())
        mapper.setSeries(series)
        chart.addSeries(mapper.series())

        self.axis_X = QtCharts.QDateTimeAxis()
        self.axis_X.setFormat("MMM yyyy")
        self.axis_Y = QtCharts.QValueAxis()

        chart.setAxisX(self.axis_X, series)
        chart.setAxisY(self.axis_Y, series)
        self.axis_Y.setRange(0, 0)
        self.axis_Y.setLabelFormat("%.0f")
        chart.setTitle("Chart")

    def addRow(self, dt, value):
        self.table.insertRow(0)
        for col, v in enumerate((dt.toMSecsSinceEpoch(), value)):
            it = QTableWidgetItem()
            it.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, v)
            self.table.setItem(0, col, it)

        if self.table.rowCount() == 1:
            self.axis_X.setRange(dt, dt.addDays(1))
            self.axis_Y.setRange(v, v)

        else:
            t_m, t_M = self.axis_X.min(), self.axis_X.max()
            t_m = min(t_m, dt)
            t_M = max(t_M, dt)

            m, M = self.axis_Y.min(), self.axis_Y.max()
            m = min(m, value)
            M = max(M, value)

            self.axis_X.setRange(t_m, t_M)
            self.axis_Y.setRange(m, M)

    def populate(self):
        for i in range(100):
            # simulate filling table with data as I get them from database.
            value = random.uniform(1, 40)
            fake_dt_str = QDate.currentDate().addDays(i).toString("dd.MM.yyyy")
            fake_value_str = str(random.uniform(0, 2))

            # Convert simulated data
            dt = QDateTime.fromString(fake_dt_str, "dd.MM.yyyy")
            value = float(fake_value_str)
            self.addRow(dt, value)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = MainWindow()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


main()
```